# URL percent encoding in Java

Tags: java, url, url-encoding

```java
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/data.php?q=%FD");
logger.info("url: " + url);
URI uri = url.toURI();
logger.info("uri ASCII: " + uri.toASCIIString());
logger.info("uri str  : " + uri.toString());
logger.info("query    : " + uri.getQuery());
logger.info("decoded  : " + URLDecoder.decode(ur.getRawQuery(), "WINDOWS-1252"));

String scheme = uri.getScheme();
String auth   = uri.getAuthority();
String path   = uri.getPath();
String query  = uri.getQuery();

URI cleanedURI = new URI(scheme, auth, path, query, null);
logger.info("cleaned uri ASCII: " + cleanedURI.toASCIIString());
logger.info("cleaned uri str  : " + cleanedURI.toString());
```

The output is:

```
url: http://www.example.com/data.php?q=%FD

uri ASCII: http://www.example.com/data.php?q=%FD
uri str  : http://www.example.com/data.php?q=%FD

query: q=�
decoded: q=ý

cleaned uri ASCII: http://www.example.com/data.php?q=%EF%BF%BD
cleaned uri str  : http://www.example.com/data.php?q=�
```

So, when I split the URI into parts, and then construct again, I cannot get back the original URL. How can I get back the original URL, which is a correctly percent-encoded, valid URL.

**Instead of getting %EF%BF%BD I need to get the original %3F.**

(Actually what I am trying to achieve is to manipulate certain parts of the URL in a clean way, such as removing the fragment, but this has not much relation to my question.)

Comment: Use `URLEncoder.encode(query, "ISO-8859-1")`.

Comment: query part is already encoded. If you encode again I get %253D%253F

Comment: `"http://www.example.com/data.php?q=" + URLEncoder.encodeURL("?", "Windows-1252")` would be the normal way around to create an URL. `request.getParameter("q")` then at the server will yield a normal question mark.

Comment: I edited my question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The URL `http://www.example.com/data.php?q=?` is same as `http://www.example.com/data.php?q=%3F`

`%3F` (or numeric 63) is nothing but the ascii code for character `'?'`.
Check it here: http://grox.net/utils/encoding.html

So, if you hit a browser with URL `%3f or '?'`; it should behave the same.

If you are much concerned with the how it displays on the console, you could try this.

```
String query  = uri.getQuery();

char charData = query.charAt(0);  // fetch the character from String

int asciiValue = (int)charData;
```

or

you could look into `String's getByte()`  method. A short tutorial is here - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_getbytes.htm

Comment: Sorry my stupidity. I edited my question. You are right q=? is the same as q=%3F.

Comment: This is really bad and rude to downvote without putting proper comment. Please put your comment, so that the answer could be improved.